# How can I use Order By with MySQL in this case?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

```
Select name, LENGTH(name) 
  from Employees 
  order by LENGTH(name);
```

Why doesn't this give me sorted Lengths? It is still sorting based on name.

Input Employees :

```
Emp | Salary
------------
DEF |  30
PQRS|  40
ABC |  30
WXY |  20
```

Expected:

```
ABC  3
DEF  3
WXY  3
PQRS 4
```

Comment: Please post your input, actual output and expected output

Comment: and the output you get. Here is what I get when I try this with MySQL 5.6 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/315e33/1/0

Comment: Note it should sort solely by length, and not by name at all. Are you using MySQL?

Answer (score 2):

Tested:

```
SELECT name, LENGTH(name) 
FROM Employees 
ORDER BY 2;
```

Then again your query seems to work as well.

Comment: It's customary to comment when downvoting. It doesn't work?

Comment: My bad, it works ...sorry ...was trying an online ide which seems to be faulty...

Comment: I think you got a down vote because most people are unaware that you can use the field number in an order by clause. You have my upvote

Answer (score 1):

Your expected output shows the data sorted by length then name, but your SQL will not guarantee that.

```
Select name, LENGTH(name) 
  from Employees 
  order by LENGTH(name), name;
```

The above modification will sort first by length, then by name, and you will get the expected output for your input.